# selenium does not click on an element, return None

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to select an option, 'No' ,and selenium cannot find this item and just ignores it and passes.
when I try to see what it finds with this element id it returns None
this is the HTML code of the element i am trying to interact with. it is not within an IFRAME.

```
<div class="form_responses"><div class="form_response"><input id="form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_1" type="radio" data-text="Yes" name="form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2" value="1" autocomplete="off" required="required" data-handler-change="1" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0"><label for="form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_1">Yes</label></div><div class="form_response"><input id="form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2" type="radio" data-text="No" name="form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2" value="0" autocomplete="off" required="required" data-handler-change="1" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0"><label for="form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2">No</label></div></div>
```

I need to sleect no

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2').click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2').click()
```

and I have tried reaching this element by XPATH, CSS SELECTOR and you name it. it just would not click on it.

Comment: No i mentioned its not inside an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

With ActionChains

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2")))
ActionChains(browser).click(element).perform()
```

With JavaScript Executor

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element )
```

Comment: i have tried this before, it just doesnt work. it scrolls into view and then i added the driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element )
but it just doesnt click on it and goes to the next line

Answer (score 0):

Wait until you find the ID.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
  EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.ID, "form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2")))
element.send_keys(keys.ENTER)

# rest of the code
```

[Waits Docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: i have tried this, it is fully loaded , Selenium finds the element and i added an if statement to see if its displayed and then asked it to click on it usnig different methods, but it does not get a click nor do i get an error, it just seems to be clicking somewhere and passing

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element )
```

Comment: I tried this method. it can be scrolled into view but doesnt get a click on this option

Answer (score 0):

it's likely that the element might not be in view.

```py
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "form_e53e9f30-0eef-4ed1-8775-a39662bb63e2_2")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()
```

Since you have tried this already, can you check if there are any overlapping elements?

Comment: i checked it all, still not getting a click on the element